# Exact same C++ code gives different ouput

Tags: c++

So before asking this question I tried to find an answer but all I found was people having mistakes in their code and/or the code wasn't actually identical.

My problem is exactly that - identical code, only difference being different file names. (Two folders, two projects, different file names, identical code except the #include line)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4PyR.jpg
Comparison of code and output. Code on the left is working and the vector size is 2 after finishing.

This is the code: (project A file name/project B file name)

## main.cpp/main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "class.h" //this would be "Card.h" in project B

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Start of main"<<endl;
    cout<<K.size()<<endl;
    K.push_back("random STR");
    cout<<K.size()<<endl;
    cout<<"End of main"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

## class.cpp/Card.cpp

```
#include "class.h" //this would be "Card.h" in project B
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> K;

Card::Card(string card_name         ,
           string card_type         ,
           bool   card_active       ,
           bool   card_discardable  ,
           bool   card_heals        ,
           bool   card_deals_damage ,
           bool   card_draws        ,
           bool   card_blocks       ,
           bool   card_discards     ,
           void (*card_pointer)()   )
{
    Name            = card_name         ;
    Type            = card_type         ;
    Active          = card_active       ;
    Discardable     = card_discardable  ;
    Heals           = card_heals        ;
    Deals_damage    = card_deals_damage ;
    Draws           = card_draws        ;
    Blocks          = card_blocks       ;
    Discards        = card_discards     ;
    Execution       = card_pointer      ;
    cout<<"Start of Class"<<endl;
    cout<<K.size()<<endl;
    K.push_back(Name);
    cout<<K[0]<<endl;
    cout<<K.size()<<endl;
    cout<<"End of Class"<<endl;
}
string Card::getName()
{
    return Name;
}
void Card::execute()
{
    Execution();
}
```

## class.h/Card.h

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

extern std::vector<std::string> K;

class Card
{
    public:
        Card(   std::string    card_name        ,
                std::string    card_type        ,
                bool           card_active      ,
                bool           card_discardable ,
                bool           card_heals       ,
                bool           card_deals_damage,
                bool           card_draws       ,
                bool           card_blocks      ,
                bool           card_discards    ,
                void (*card_pointer)()          );
        std::string getName();
        void execute();
    private:
        std::string Name        ;
        std::string Type        ;
        bool        Active      ;
        bool        Discardable ;
        bool        Heals       ;
        bool        Deals_damage;
        bool        Draws       ;
        bool        Blocks      ;
        bool        Discards    ;
        void      (*Execution)();
};



#endif
```

## aFile.cpp/test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class.h"
void execute_stab()
{
    std::cout<<"You dealt 2 dmg to enemy player"<<std::endl;
}
Card Stab("Stab", "Offensive", false, true, false, true, false, false, false, execute_stab);
```

output is in the album, for those who can't use imgur here it is:

Project A:

```
Start of Class
0
1
Stab
End of Class
Start of main
1
2
End of main
```

Project B:

```
Start of Class
0
1
Stab
End of Class
Start of main
0
1
End of main
```

I apologize if my code is messy or I'm doing things in a dumb way, I've just started learning C++ and this was my attempt at creating a card game. So the big question is why is identical code giving different outputs? 
Thank you

Comment: Try to trim it down to a [MCVE]. The process if trimming it down may help you find the bug, and it will certainly make it easier for us to try to reproduce it. At the moment there's just too much extraneous code for a good question.

Comment: You could also try preprocessing the two versions, which will just process `#include`s and macros, then comparing the result to see where the difference actually is. With g++ or clang++, you do this with the `-E` option.

Comment: @BoBTFish there is no bug, the code is working perfectly on my project A. Question is why is the identical copy not working.

Comment: If there was no bug, you wouldn't be here asking the question... You just don't know where the bug is (which is fine, that's what the site is for). As it happens, my comment was not so helpful, Some Programmer Dude has already identified the bug. (And it really is a bug).

Comment: @MantasKandratavicius If two compilers cause the same code to produce two different behaviors and the difference is unexpected (not intended), then it's indicative that you likely have *undefined behavior* which is by definition a bug. No compiler errors is so very very different than having no bugs.

Comment: Also I should've added that I'm using same compiler for both projects.

Comment: *Undefined Behaviour* is a concept in C++ (and related languages, e.g. C) where the language doesn't hold your hand. If you do something illegal, you may not get an error message. It may crash, it may even appear to work, and only give weird output occasionally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of initialization of global variables is only well-defined for a single [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). The order between translation units is *undefined*. That's what's happening here.

You can't know if `K` from `Card.cpp` will be initialized first, or `Stab` from `test.cpp`.

Comment: Shouldn't that break both projects? I don't understand why it's working as intended on my project A then. Thanks for the answer tho, I'll attempt to fix it.

Comment: @MantasKandratavicius That's *undefined behavior* for you. Sometimes it seems to work fine, and in the next minute it will simply break down.

Comment: I see, thank you. I'll read that thoroughly. I guess this answers my question.